# How to filter json data using search bar

Tags: json, swift, filter, uisearchbar

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{

    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    let lists:Array = searchCollectionList1 as Array
   // let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "assetname CONTAINS[C] %@", searchText)
    let searchPredicate = searchFilter(searchName: searchText) 'Constant 'searchPredicate' inferred to have type '()', which may be unexpected'
    let array = (lists as NSArray).adding(searchPredicate)
    filteredDataItems = array

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `NSPredicate`, use native `filter`.

`range(of ... ) != nil` with option `.caseInsensitive` does exactly the same as `CONTAINS[C]`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{

    searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    filteredDataItems = searchCollectionList1.filter{ $0.assetname.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This assumes that `searchCollectionList1` and `filteredDataItems` are the same type.